# I tried to create a login form in fixed password in php

Tags: php

I tried to create a login form in fixed password in php.this is my form its not display the error msg ,i like to create username anything no problem but password is constant like ex:abcd it is the password for every username.

```html
 <form  action="test.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="logintable ">
                        <table  class="applyfont" style="border: 1px solid lightseagreen">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr id="login1">
                                    <td class="applyfontbold"><b>Login page </b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Username or Email" id="uname">
                                          <span>
                                            <?php if(isset($_GET['nameErr']))
                                            echo $_GET['nameErr'];
                                            ?>
                                        </span>  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                                        <span>
                                            <?php if(isset($_GET['passeErr']))
                                            echo $_GET['passeErr'];
                                            ?>
                                        </span> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td>
                                        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit"> </p>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="login-help applyfontlighter">
                                            <p>Forgot your password? <span id="footer"><u style="color:red;"><a href="#">Click here to reset it.</a></u></span></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <p id="new"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" >New Registers</button></p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody> 
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

```html
<?php

$passeErr = $nameErr = "";
$password = $name = "";
$x = "typepass";


if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
       header("Location:http://localhost/Archimage/login.html?nameErr=$nameErr");
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $passeErr = "password is required";
         header("Location:http://localhost/Archimage/login.html?passeErr=$passeErr");
    } elseif ($password !== $x) {
        $passeErr = "password doesn't match";
         header("Location:http://localhost/Archimage/login.html?passeErr=$passeErr");
    } else {
        $password = test_input($_POST['password']);
    }
    
    echo "Username : " . $name . "<br>" . "Password :" . " " . $password;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see in your code, password is defined like this

```
$password = $name = "";
```

So when you compare with an empty value, and not with the $_POST value from form.

the comparation will be

```
 elseif ($_POST['password']!== $x) {
```

expect help you

Comment: i don't get the answer after removing 
$password = $name = "";

Comment: and put the comparison correctly ...but not get it plz give me a solution

Comment: remove white spaces between dots in this line of echo

Comment: what is tes_input function where is defiened, or what is the use

Answer (score 2):

Use this one and test it

```html
elseif ($_POST['password'] !== $x) {
```

Here  you are matching password with null values.
so this will not going to work.

Comment: i remove white space also

Comment: it shows fatal error and ask me to check line 10 in php  this is the 10th line   $name = test_input($_POST['name']);

Comment: where is test_input() function?

Comment: by the way what was the problem?